# Ionic BLE writing to other devices

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

My app is currently connected to a device that I am trying to write with.

Log: Message we are trying to send is "Hello"

```
⚡️  [log] - WE ARE CURRENTLY CONNECTED
To Native Cordova ->  BLE writeWithoutResponse BLE46928892 ["options": 
[027B18C5-15E6-86C1-ADDC-B2475099CDA0, 6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9- 
E50E24DCCA9E, 6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, {
    0 = 72;
    1 = 69;
    2 = 76;
    3 = 76;
    4 = 79;
}]]
2020-03-17 16:16:19.223013-0400 App[5985:1842762] writeWithoutResponse
2020-03-17 16:16:19.223160-0400 App[5985:1842762] getData
2020-03-17 16:16:19.223308-0400 App[5985:1842762] Looking for 
6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E with properties 4
```

The issue I'm having is the writing function in BLE.

```
(method) BLE.write(deviceId: string, serviceUUID: string, characteristicUUID: string, value: 
ArrayBuffer): Promise<any>
```

.TS

```
import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble/ngx';

devices:any[] = [];
id;

constructor(
public plt: Platform,
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private ble: BLE,
private ngZone: NgZone,
private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
) { }


connect(count:number){

this.ble.connect(this.devices[count].id).subscribe
(peripheralData => {
      console.log(peripheralData);

    },
    peripheralData => {
      console.log('disconnected');
    });;

    this.id = this.devices[count].id;

}

write(){
    if (this.ble.isConnected){
      console.log("WE ARE CURRENTLY CONNECTED");
    var string = "HELLO"

    var array = new Uint8Array(string.length);
    for (var x = 0, l = string.length; x < l; x++)
      {array[x] = string.charCodeAt(x);}

    this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(this.id, "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9- 
    E50E24DCCA9E", 
    "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E", array);
  }
  else{
    console.log("WE ARE NOT CONNECTED");
  }

}
```

EDIT: I turned this into two functions so I don't have to worry about the promise errors anymore. Log shows that we are calling the function and we are connected to the BLE device.
Still, the message doesn't actually send.

Comment: The way you've written this, you seem to be writing before the connection completes. I would expect `.connect` to return a Promise that you need to chain to at a minimum. Getting all the way from connection to the ability to write to a characteristic is a complex, multi-step (and highly async) process in BLE, and I don't know how much of that Ionic is abstracting for you, but you definitely can't write before the connection completes. I don't know the syntax here, but I would expect you to put the `this.ble.write` inside the first closure.

Comment: I edited the code to fit what you said, I actually was get an unhandled promise. Unhandled Promise rejection:

Comment: Dang, even with the way it's written now, I'm still getting an unhandled promise rejection, I'll look into that.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anything about Ionic, but I'd expect `write` to return a promise, and you don't deal with that. Note that there are several steps required between connection and write. I don't know if Ionic does all of those for you automatically. You need to discover the services, and for each service you need to discover the characteristics. Definitely on iOS there is no way that Ionic could go directly from a UUID to writing without a discover step.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it worked

.TS

```
import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble/ngx';


export class AddDeviceComponent implements OnInit {

routeParams;
SCAN_RESULT_COUNT = 20;
scanResult;
id;



constructor(
public plt: Platform,
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private ble: BLE,
private ngZone: NgZone,
private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
) { }


connect(count:number){

this.ble.connect(this.devices[count].id).subscribe
(peripheralData => {
  console.log(peripheralData);

},
peripheralData => {
  console.log('disconnected');
});;

this.id = this.devices[count].id;

}



  write(){
if (this.ble.isConnected)
{
  console.log("WE ARE CURRENTLY CONNECTED");
var string = "HELLO"

var array = new Uint8Array(string.length);
for (var x = 0, l = string.length; x < l; x++) {
  array[x] = string.charCodeAt(x);
}


// this is what needed to be done
this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(this.id, "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9- 
E50E24DCCA9E".toLowerCase(), 
 "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E".toLowerCase(), array.buffer);



}
else{
 console.log("WE ARE NOT CONNECTED HELP");
}

}
}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to get it to consistently send? It seems completely random for me.

Comment: Yeah I got it to work! After I made this post, I refined the code so it looked somewhat cleaner. Been awhile since I worked with this project, but it works.

Comment: Awesome. Would you happen to have a working example or a repo?

Comment: Yeah, might take awhile for me to find it. Believe this feature got scrapped awhile back. But it should still be on github as an Old Commit, just need to dig through when I can find it.

Comment: @Austin I wrote the code on the Pastebin. It's about a year old. https://pastebin.com/4VPegzrh let me know if you have any questions. If I recall, everything worked last time I used this.